# ArcGIS for Android API Example/Tutorials

Tags: references, arcgis-android

I know that the ArcGIS API for Android is still in beta (I've joined the beta program), but I was curious if anyone had produced or discovered any examples/tutorials/cookbooks for the API. The [Help Resource](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/help/) is still severely limited. I have watched the [ArcGIS API for Android Videos](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/video/arcgis-android), but they do not provide any of the source code (contrary to what is stated in the videos themselves). I have also browsed through the [API Reference](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/api/index.html) but I've found the documentation to be lacking.

Comment: INAL so I don't know if I am allowed to re-post information found in the beta program (it is not very clear in the Legal/Non-Disclosure Agreement), but there is a wealth (comparatively speaking) of questions and answers in the ArcGIS API for Android Discussion forum located in the beta program dashboard. Specific to my earlier post, if you browse through the posts there is one entitled **Source Code from DS 2011 ?** a link is posted to the source code to the Water Service application video from above. *If someone will look at the NDA and can tell me if I can post the link directly I will.*

Comment: sbaskin: Making CW at your request, anticipating that (eventually) this question might collect a list of resources rather than one best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it turns out I cannot share this information then I will remove the link; furthermore, the section **Access and Use Constraints** should address anyone's concerns. Here is the [application code](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6e0512016fdd4f6ab4e47b2eb64a347d) for the Water Service application showcased in the video from the above post titled *DS2011: Introduction to ArcGIS API for Android*.

Answer (score 1):

since you posted the question, the SDK was released. You can find information at 1.0.1 [ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/arcgis-android/sdk) which includes a [Hello World Map](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/android/help/#/Hello_World_Map/011900000005000000/) sample.

Some warnings about switching to the Release SDK (if you had been working with the Beta) are:

- Install the latest Android SDK R16 (R13 stopped working for me).

  - At least R14 is required to get around the "no crunch" error.
- Install the latest Eclipse 3.7 (3.5 Galileo no longer worked for me).

  - At least Eclipse 3.6 is required to support the latest ADT Plugin.
- Developing with the Emulator is no longer supported.

  - The SDK now uses OpenGL ES 2.0 which, currently, doesn't work in the emulator.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info. As I was interested in this to begin with, you can rest assured I started playing with the release the day it was out. I'm not sure if it was mentioned elsewhere on the site, so thanks for putting it up for others.